Array inside array sqlalchemy
I try to get array inside another array with in my code. I have sql query. It looks like this and works good!
SELECT array_agg(array[CAST(EXTRACT(epoch FROM subquery.timestamp) AS BIGINT), subquery.count]) AS "some"
FROM (
    SELECT 
        some_table.timestamp AS timestamp,
        count(some_table.any) AS count
    FROM 
        some_table
    GROUP BY 
        some_table.timestamp
    ORDER BY 
        some_table.timestamp
) AS subquery;

I want write it in sqlalchemy. I get this
subquery = (sa.select(
                some_table.c.timestamp,
                sa.func.count(some_table.c.any).label("count"),
            ).group_by(some_table.c.timestamp)
            .order_by(some_table.c.timestamp)
            .alias("subquery"))

insert_query = (sa.select(
                  sa.func.array_agg(
                    sa.func.array(
                      sa.cast(sa.func.EXTRACT("epoch", subquery.c.timestamp), sa.BigInteger),
                                subquery.c.count)).label("some"))
            .select_from(subquery)

I get the same sql BUT:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CAST"
LINE 1: SELECT array_agg(array(CAST(EXTRACT(epoch FROM subquery.time...

All problems in parentheses. What do I Should change in my sqlalchemy query?

are you on postgres?

if you are on postgres, then this seems to work subquery = select(some_table.c.timestamp, func.count(some_table.c.any).label("count")).group_by(some_table.c.timestamp).order_by(some_table.c.timestamp).subquery("subquery") and insert_query = select(func.array_agg(array([cast(extract("epoch", subquery.c.timestamp), BIGINT), subquery.c.count])).label("some")) all the imports are from sqlachemy except array which is from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array

You are right! Thank you!
